# show that $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}{e^{z}}=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Suppose that $p(z)$ is a polynomial with complex coefficient and $z \in \mathbb{C}. $Show that $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}{p(z)}=\infty$ and $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}{e^{z}}=\infty$

For $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty}{e^{z}}=\infty$, I start with $|e^{z}|>M$ where $M \in \mathbb{R}$. Then we have $|e^{z}|=e^x$ where $z=x+iy$. Also $|z|>N$ where $N \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \sqrt{x^2+y^2}>N$ . Then I stuck at here.

I am not so confident to prove limit in complex variable. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: $\lim_{z\to \infty} e^z$ doesn't exist. To prove the first equality write $p(z)=z^n(a_n+\ldots+\frac{a_0}{z^n})$ with $a_n\ne 0$.

Comment: You only have $e^z \to \infty$ if $\Re z \to +\infty$.

Comment: In fact, $\displaystyle \lim_{z\to \infty}f(z)=\infty$ characterizes polynomials--this just says that $f$ has a pole at infinity, for which it is then a common fact that $f$ must be a polynomial.

Comment: @Idontknow, perhaps you forgot some absolute values in the limits? We have real and imaginary parts here, so $\,z\to \infty\;$ doesn't tells the whole story about the *complex* variable $\;z\;$ ...

Comment: @njguliyev: regarding the first equality, after factoring out $z^n$, i get $|z^n||\sum_{k=0}^n{a_kz^{k-n}}|$

Comment: @Idonknow, now find the limits of each factor.